# How to compare the elements of two matrices in c

Tags: c

How can i compare elements of one matrix with the elements of other matrix? what is the concept of regression in comparing the elements of two matrices?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're just starting out, so I recommend learning about linear search, which involves comparing each of the array elements one by one.

Determine this size of your arrays.
For i=0 through i=arraysize check if arrayA[i] is equal to arrayB[i].
If you find an instance where they are not equal, then your arrays are not equal.